# Numpy 1.11.2 64 bit Windows

Tags: python, windows, numpy

Is there is a link to download **Numpy** version **1.11.2** *64 bit* for Windows?
I have come across [Unofficial Windows Binaries for Python Extension Packages](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/). But there are currently only 1.11.3 and 1.12.0 versions available to download.

Comment: Just to clarify, OP wants an old version -- the latest is 1.12.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Numpy Version 1.11.2 windows wheels are available on [pypi](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/numpy/1.11.2).